# HTML Table - Add a second table row

Tags: html, html-table

I need your help with adding a second table row to the following [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7cs8d6vr/):

```
   <body>

<h1>TEST</h1>

<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">#</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Title 1</th>
            <th colspan="3">Title 2</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- I tried adding another table row but the output was not what I expected. The Roman numbers should         appear under "Title 2".
        <tr>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>II</th>
            <th>III</th>
        </tr>
        -->
        <tr>
            <th>I <br>- Lorem ipsum dolor.<br> - Lorem ipsum dolor<br> - Lorem ipsum dolor </th>
            <th>II <br> Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th>III <br> Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>        
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor<sup>*1</sup><br> a)lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b) Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>

</table>    


</body>
```

When I add the second table row, the content shifts one space to the left.

What am I doing wrong? At first I thought it was a rowspan issue, but I modified the value of "Title 1" to 3 in order to accommodate the new row and the issue is still present.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: You mean...you want all of the content underneath the second-to-leftmost column to move to the right?

Answer (score 2):

### What causes your problem

The issue is caused by the `rowspan`s on `<th rowspan="2">#</th>` and `<th rowspan="3">Title 1</th>`.

Having property `rowspan="n"` as the property of a table cell basically means that your table cell stretches across multiple rows, with `n` being equal to the number of rows you want it to stretch across (aka `span` across).

---

### How to solve your problem

To fix your problem, you need to make sure that the value of `rowspan` for both `<th rowspan="2">#</th>` and `<th rowspan="3">Title 1</th>` is equal to the number of rows on the left of them.

As you want to have 3 rows there and `<th rowspan="3">Title 1</th>` already has a `rowspan` of 3, this means that you would really only need to change `<th rowspan="2">#</th>` to `<th rowspan="3">#</th>`.

---

### The result

Here's what your code should looks like, after applying the fix :

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table td,
.table tr,
.table th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">#</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Title 1</th>
            <th colspan="3">Title 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>II</th>
            <th>III</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>- Lorem ipsum dolor.<br> - Lorem ipsum dolor<br> - Lorem ipsum dolor </th>
            <th>Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th>Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
        </tr>
    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>        
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor<sup>*1</sup><br> a)lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b) Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### A Fiddle

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7cs8d6vr/4/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I totally forgot about the "#", much appreciated!